# How to populate range of NULLs with last known value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which contains data of users for each app they connected to, their respective date of connection and balance. For the dates where they don't log in, the cte3 joint table generated from my query below will return NULL values.

I am trying to build a query where I want to replace for each user the NULL values. The idea is to take the last known value for each of the three fields (e.g. user_id, app_id and balance). I've found similar topics which have helped me but I am currently stuck. In my below query, I am trying to use the LAG() function but it only works for the following day, not the full range of NULL values. Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

```sql
with cte1 as (
select distinct c.date 
from core_table c
where c.date >= '2023-01-01'
),
cte2 as (
select c.date, c.user_id, c.app_id, c.balance 
from core_table c
),
cte3 as (
select cte1.date, cte2.user_id, cte2.app_id, c.balance  
from cte1 
left join cte2 on cte1.date = cte2.date
)
select date, 
case when user_id is NULL then lag(user_id) over (order by date) else user_id end as user_id,
case when app_id is NULL then lag(app_id) over (order by date) else app_id end as app_id,
case when balance is NULL then lag(balance) over (order by date) else balance end as balance
from cte3
```

As an example, this is what I have:

| date | user_id | app_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-02 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-02 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | 3 | 5 | 18 |

This is what I want:

| date | user_id | app_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-02 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-03 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-04 | 3 | 5 | 18 |

My query tested on one single user (let's say user_id 1) returns this:

| date | user_id | app_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 15 |

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: How do you distinguish that the 2nd row belongs to user_id=1 and 11th row belongs to user_id=3? They are absolutely identical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I am understanding what you are trying to do. This will give you a set of dates with a balance for each user_id/app_id pair:

```sql
with cte1 as (
    select distinct date 
    from core_table
    where date >= '2023-01-01'
),
cte2 as (
    select distinct user_id, app_id
    from core_table
    where date >= '2023-01-01'
    and user_id is not null
    and app_id is not null
)
select
    cte1.date, cte2.user_id, cte2.app_id,
    (
        select balance
        from core_table
        where user_id = cte2.user_id
        and app_id = cte2.app_id
        and date <= cte1.date
        order by date desc
        limit 1
    ) as balance
from cte1
cross join cte2
order by cte2.user_id, cte2.app_id, cte1.date;
```

Outputs:

| date | user_id | app_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-02 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-03 | 3 | 5 | 42 |
| 2023-01-04 | 3 | 5 | 18 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3 | 5 | 18 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEwv90wa).

It would probably be better to replace `cte1` with a [recursive cte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series) that builds a contiguous set of dates, for a given start/end date.